# pivot table not counting properly

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to use a pivot table to show the number of product sales (total sale_units sold) by region.

Here is the desired outcome:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
select * from 
(
    select p_code, reg_name, sale_units
    from dwregion, dwsalesfact
)
pivot
(
    sum(sale_units)
    for reg_name
    in ('ne', 'nw', 'se', 'sw')
)
```

This currently gives me the cross tabular format that I'm looking for, however the values are all empty (as in they all have a single dash mark in each cell)

I have tried `count(sale_units)` as well but I just ended up with 0's in my pivot table.

How would I fix this to get my desired output?

Also I'm using Oracle live and you can find the script file [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/lmv7m7x9s3ff0unh66w6p5fsh).

**EDIT:** Even though Paul Maxwell shows the proper join statements in the code block, I marked mathguy as having the best solution as he refers to Paul in his answer as well as identify and solve why I was not receiving an output.

Comment: please share ample data

Comment: I just saw your **EDIT**. While Paul Maxwell shows the corrections to the `join` part of your query, his answer does not, in fact, address the main problem - he still has the same values in the `IN` list of `PIVOT`, in lower-case. He did not identify the reason you weren't getting any results, which was the question you asked (while he did, indeed, identify a different problem and explained how to fix it). I believe that would be the better reason to mark my answer as the "correct" one - it actually answered the specific question you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table and column names (and other identifiers) are generally not case sensitive, so you may refer to a table as `EMPLOYEES` or `employees` or `Employees`, etc.

But the same is not true of text values, and in the `IN` list of the `PIVOT` operator that is what you are using: the text values of region names. In your tables, they are defined as `'NE'`, `'NW'` etc., but in your query you reference them as `'ne'`, `'nw'` etc. You may have a large number of sales in the `'NE'` region, but none at all in the `'ne'` region; in fact, that region doesn't even exist in your tables. To you and me `'ne'` may look the same as `'NE'`, but not to a computer - not unless you somehow tell it so, and in your case, you don't.

Paul Maxwell is probably right regarding the missing join conditions, but the reason you aren't getting any counts at all is what I just explained. You may need to fix your query with suggestions from both answers.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't established any definite relationship from the fact table to the region. (Although you created a cartesian product/cross join, but that will not be accurate here.) You need to join both the customer and region tables I believe:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT fact.p_code
         , reg.reg_name
         , fact.sale_units
    FROM dwsalesfact fact
    INNER JOIN DWCUSTOMER cust ON fact.cus_code = cust.cust_code
    INNER JOIN DWREGION reg ON cust.reg_id = reg.reg_id
    )
PIVOT(
    SUM(sale_units) 
    FOR reg_name IN ( 'ne' ,'nw' ,'se' ,'sw' )
    )
```